# Using basscss installed via NPM/Webpack

Tags: css, npm, webpack

I'm trying to install Basscss CSS framework in my webpack/react app, I'm fairly new to this workflow.

When I run 'npm i basscss' I'm able to add:

`require('basscss/css/basscss.css');`

To my app entrypoint. However, I now need to add basscss-addons for further styling - so is the correct approach to add a require line for every single file in basscss-addons? Each addon is a separate file, and each addon's folder structure seems to be different.

It seems like there must be an easier way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a method in [this article](http://jxnblk.com/writing/posts/static-site-generation-with-react-and-webpack/) that works, but it relies on cssnext and it throws warnings saying it's deprecated and that you need to upgrade to postcss instead.

So you would need to use postcss, postcss-basscss and postcss-import, I guess, but I couldn't make it work efficiently. I'd love to hear from someone who has a valid implementation with postcss...